# Response page cannot call jquery function on main page

Tags: jquery, ajax, class, response

Why the link on response page (test.html) cannot call jquery on the main page? eventhough both links have same class, please help what do I have to do to make it works.

main page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".comment_link").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test.html",
                    success: function (cont) {
                        if (cont) {
                            $("#view" ).append(cont);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
    });
    });
    </script>

    <div id="view"></div>
    <a href="#" class="comment_link">add comment</a>
```

file content of test.html :

```
    Helloo
    <a href="#" class="comment_link">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation - *as you are adding `comment_link` dynamically*

```
$(document).on('click',".comment_link",function (){...});
```

You need to change your code like this -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', ".comment_link", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.html",
            success: function (cont) {
                if (cont) {
                    $("#view").append(cont);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to replace all your code inside script tags with what i posted - after the line _You need to change your code like this_

Answer (score 1):

The element is 'newly' created, so you have to bind events to it...

Using the `on()` method.  (used to be `live()` but thats deprecated)

```
$('body').on('click','.comment_link',function(){..//your code here..});
```

So you'll wanna put your ajax in a function, so you can call it on click, and delegate it to new elements as well....without rewriting the code...you don't have to do this, just makes it easier to reuse etc

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     //Assign click handler         
     $('body').on('click','.comment_link', getAjax);

         //Your Ajax call put into function
         function getAjax(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.html",
                success: function (cont) {
                    if (cont) {
                        $("#view" ).append(cont);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
           };

  });
```